# Probability of finding a power of 2

Tags: probability

Imagine I have set of numbers $(0,n]$. The problem I have in mind is to find the probability that the number I pick (randomly), from this set, is a power of $2$.

So I thought that I could use simply calculate the ratio of number of desired terms to total numbers in the set. Lets say there's a number $k$ such that $k$ is a power of $2$ and $k\leq n$. So, there must be $\log_{2}{k}$ other powers of $2$ that are contained in the set. I've used this reasoning to say that the probability must therefore be: 
$$ P=\frac{\log_{2}{n}}{n}=\frac{\ln{n}}{n\ln{2}}$$
My question is: Is this result correct? I understand if this must only be an approximation, in which case does a more accurate expression exist?

EDIT:

There's an addition I think I should mention: I could re-define the probability in terms of the floor function as:
$$ P=\frac{\left \lfloor{\log_{2}{n}}\right \rfloor}{n}$$
Is this correct?

Comment: I don't know if it's correct but it's exactly what I would do and I'd argue and defend it and declare myself correct until someone who knows better tells me and convinces me otherwise.  So I'm declaring it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost correct.

Since $1$ is also a power of $2$, the probability is $\dfrac{\left\lfloor{\log_{2}{n}}\right\rfloor\color\red{+1}}{n}$